# What's causing the failure of my rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

When I generate the model, for my app, I end up with an error.

Model generator code: `rails g model Product title:string brand:string url:string`

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
bin/rails:3:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /Users/asaignment/projects/productsboard/config/boot (LoadError)
```

What is causing the inability to load the file?

Comment: make sure your `bundle install` works before this step! Do check your `config/boot.rb` this looks like a path issue

Comment: Updated OS and rails and it's working now - thanks!